# Strategy for JavaScript interpreter implementation (functions) -- am I making sense?

Tags: javascript, compiler-construction, interpreter

I'm writing a js-to-js interpreter (that is, a Javascript program that takes a Javascript program as an argument and executes it).  I'm not trained in compiler theory, I'm just faking it.  The expression-evaluation machine is working (using a kind of clunky operator-precedence algorithm), but not yet for functions.  So here's my question.

The way I'm thinking of implementing functions looks something like this: When a function is invoked, I'll create a namespace / context for it, also allowing access to the namespaces of enclosing functions and the global namespace.

I'm not yet implementing closures, but these namespaces are designed to work for them.  Basically, as I understand it, closures are just the way Javascript refuses to forget the context of a function when it hasn't forgotten the variable which holds the function.

So, when the function is invoked, I'll pass into its context object a copy of the statement which invokes it, along with a pointer to the expression that triggered the function call.  Each expression in that statement that has been evaluated already will remember its value.  When we return from the function, that statement becomes the current statement, and I start to execute it again -- but I don't re-evaluate expressions that have already been evaluated, including the function just completed.  So then I go merrily along with the rest of the statement, potentially calling more functions, etc.

Each statement, expression, and function has an abstract representation built during parsing.  During execution, only the current statement has any actual existence, aside from that abstract representation, because really all I need to remember at any given time is:

- variables in the current context
- variables in enclosing contexts (that is, the most recent invocation of a function -- including the global context -- which encloses the current function)
- the current statement
- what statement is next
- what blocks I'm inside of (just so I know what to do when I hit
  the end of one)
- the call stack, which is a stack of contexts including variables and the
  statement that triggered the call, with its expressions.
- A pointer to the specific expression to update with return value from the function / context.

So am I making sense?  Thanks for your help!

Comment: Why are you doing this and not simply using eval()?

Comment: Because I want to implement a user-friendly debugger.  I haven't explained the whole project, but I need very granular control of the interface, and I won't get it if I have eval() do all the heavy lifting for me.  Thanks for your assistance.

Answer (score 1):

What you're describing is basically what an interpreter does, yes, but I'd still strongly recommend rethinking your approach. Interpreting Javascript in Javascript is going to run extremely slowly as soon as you're doing anything more complex than adding numbers. Is there some reason you can't separate your debugger from actual execution? If that's not possible, I'd really suggest doing your interpreter in a plug-in or something that gives you lower level speed. Or consider mod'ing something like this: https://developers.google.com/blockly/installation/js-interpreter?hl=en

Comment: Thanks.  I will probably end up adding the ability to run the code in eval() as well as in the debugger, so it can run quickly when not interrupted.  In any case, to run in the debugger, I need to have the whole JS environment running in JS, since I need the ability to deal with expressions and variable in granular fashion.  The harness for eval() will be pretty complicated though.